PHP MySQL Data Not Pulling Up on HTML Page
I'm completely new to PHP and I'm trying to pull up info data from phpmyadmin when the user clicks the link in the side navbar and show it on my html page using Ajax replacing the image I originally had there. The problem now is that I can't get the data to show when I click the link.
   <?php

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost:3308', 'dev14dbuser', 'iYzcKDu8pROZ3SXc','dev14db');
    
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection error: " . mysqli_connect_error($conn));
    }
    
    $sql = "SELECT Stat FROM `totk` ORDER BY Stat";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    
    echo "<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Location Found</th>
    <th>Stat</th>
    <th>Image</th>
    </tr>";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        
        
        echo "<td>" . $row["Name"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["Description"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["Location"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["Stat"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["Image"] . "</td>";
        echo '</tr>';
    }
        echo '</table>';

        mysqli_close($conn);
        ?> 


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        
      function myAjax() {
        $('.zmdi').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
        });
        document.getElementById("center").style.display = "none";
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {            
          
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
          // console.log(this.responseText);
          // } else {
          //   alert('Error Code: ' + xmlhttp.status);
          //   alert('Error Message: ' + xmlhttp.statusText);
          // }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getarmor.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send(); 
      
      }

      function myAjab() {
        $('.zmdi').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
        });
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("center").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
          // } else {
          //   alert('Error Code: ' + xmlhttp.status);
          //   alert('Error Message: ' + xmlhttp.statusText);
          // }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getstat.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }

      

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="viewport">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="nav-placeholder">

        </div>
        <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#nav-placeholder").load("nav.html");
        });
        </script>
        <div id="content">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div id="txtHint"></div>
                <img id="center" src="zelda-totk-view2.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="container-fluid">
            
           
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <br>
</body>
</html>

This is the navbar
`<div id="sidebar">
        <header>
          <a href="index.html">
              <img id="logo" src="TotK_Logo.webp" alt="">Head Armors</a>
        </header>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li>
            <a href="" onclick="myAjax()">
              <i class="zmdi zmdi-view-dashboard"></i> View All
            </a>
          </li>

          <li>
              <a href="" onclick="myAjab()">
                  <i class="zmdi zmdi-stats"></i>Stats
              </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="map.html">
              <i class="zmdi zmdi-map"></i> Map 
            </a>
          </li>
          
        </ul>
      </div>`

I've made sure that the database is successfully connected and I can see everything when I go directly to the php page but the data just doesn't show up when I click on the link on the html page.

Does the AJAX event fire? If so what is the response that comes back? You need to do more debugging. Use the developer console, look that up if unsure what that is/how to use it. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools

I think it does fire. I added an alert('Error Code: ' + xmlhttp.status); and and alert('Error Message: ' + xmlhttp.statusText). The alerts do pop up. Usuallly the error code says 0 and no message. But sometimes(after a few more clicks), the error code would say 200 and the message becomes ok. After that the data would display for half a second then immediately disappear.

Side note: PHPMyAdmin is just a web based management tool for managing MySQL databases. Your application is connecting directly to MySQL and has nothing to do with PHPMyAdmin.

Possibly the page is refreshing at the same because you are not preventing the default behaviour of those links in your javascript functions

Use your browser's Developer Tools - particularly the Network tool, to check what's going on

You are calling preventDefault() on the click event on <i class="zmdi ..."></i>, not the anchors. Instead of $('.zmdi').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }); just use event.preventDefault();. Your opening/closing curly braces are not matched up for the JS functions (due to commented code). Your myAjax() and myAjab() functions are essentially the same, apart from the name of partial being loaded. Use one function and pass in the href of the partial to be loaded.
